# Alternatives to using the .Select property in a Do Until loop

Tags: vba, excel, select

I'm trying to run a simple nested If & Do Until loop for multiple sheets:

```
Sub DoUntil()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
       For i = 1 To 25
            If ws.Cells(i, 10) = "T" Then
                ws.Cells(i, 10).Select

                Do Until ActiveCell = "P"
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1) = 1
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
                Loop
            End If
       Next i
Next ws
End Sub
```

PURPOSE: This function is meant to loop through a column, and place 1's in the next column to the right. The 1's must start just after "T" and end at "P". The T's and P's are unevenly spaced.

PROBLEM: Running this code for a single worksheet without the ws. object gives no problem. However, as soon as I want to loop through multiple worksheets, the .Select fails to fetch the specified range (Error 1004). This error is given at

```
ws.Cells(i, 10).Select
```

QUESTION: I know the perils of using the .Select property, but I'm unsure of how to tackle this problem differently as the ActiveCell is crucial for my Do Until function. Is there another way to run my Do Until function that will work with the If statement and loop through multiple sheets?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below:

```
Sub DoUntil()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer, j as Integer
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
       For i = 1 To 25
            If ws.Cells(i, 10) = "T" Then
                j = i

                Do Until ws.Cells(j,10) = "P"
                ws.Cells(j, 10+1) = 1
                j = j + 1
                Loop
            End If
       Next i
Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

use match, something like
`cells(match("T",range("a1:a50000"),0),1)` to 
`cells(match("P",range("a" & match("T",range("a1:a50000"),0)  & ":a50000"),0),1)`

and something like

`range(cells(y,x),cells(y2,x2)).offset(0,1).value=1`